# AWS Batch unmanaged compute env cant schedule jobs on a autoscaler enabled ECS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-batch

We have the following setup:

1. AWS batch job with an unmanaged compute environment (we need this because we use GPU and custom disk sizes, and managed environment with Launch templates are not working. But that should be a different bug report).
2. The automatically created ECS cluster is enabled with a EC2 Autoscaling group Capacity provider.
3. The Autoscaling group has a target tracking dynamic scaling policy which tracks the metric AWS/ECS/ManagedScaling > CapacityProviderReservation.

The min size of the ASG is 0, so during idle periods there are no instances running on the ASG. When we schedule a Batch job at this point, the job becomes stuck in RUNNABLE state until we somehow manually trigger a scale up of the ASG. I think the reason is because Batch sees the ECS cluster and thinks well there are no resources to schedule the job, so I will keep the job in RUNNABLE state. But only if the Batch starts a Task on ECS, then ECS CapacityProviderReservation metric can change and it will trigger an scale up. One can see how it leads to a dead end. Now, we have verified all the related permissions and present and there are no capacity issues. If we scale up the ASG the job gets scheduled as expected. The scale down after the job finishes also works fine and the ASG/ECS cluster returns to 0 instances after.

Have anyone else face a similar issue and found a solution?

Comment: I've dealt with a similar situation running GPU instances in Batch and I never had to resort to unmanaged compute environments. I simply selected a GPU instance type (i.e. g4dn.xlarge) in the compute environment and added a GPU requirement to the job definition. Your requirement of custom disk sizes may be more of a challenge, but you do have the option of using EFS (I believe through a custom AMI), or you could use the local disk on SSD-enabled instances (such as g4dn) through volumes. You can also attach a custom EBS volume, but that same volume would be attached to all jobs.

Comment: Thanks, and yes using a different AMI or additional EBS or even mounting instance store volumes are all an option. But those can only be done via custom launch templates. Batch integration with custom launch templates are horribly broken. For example, when I create a Batch managed env with a custom launch template, AWS doesnt even create a ASG and therefore no capacity is being made available in the cluster again. Thus no jobs can be run. This is what I meant by "managed environment with Launch templates are not working. But that should be a different bug report"